# Value of type '_' has no member

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

In the cb.check(self.rowChecked[indexPath.row]) line under cellForRowAt I'm getting a "Value of type 'LolFirstTableViewController' has no member 'rowChecked'" even though I set up rowChecked to be an array of Booleans with tasks.count number of items. Do I need to initialize rowChecked somewhere else besides cellForRowAt or what am I doing wrong here? The point of this code is to make a checkbox show up in each cell of a table where you can click it to change the accessory to a check mark, and click it again to uncheck it. The check box itself is a separate custom class called CheckButton. I'm still learning Swift so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class LoLFirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tasks:[Task] = taskData

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLFirstTableViewController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func saveAddTask(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let AddTaskTableViewController = segue.source as? AddTaskTableViewController {

            if let task = AddTaskTableViewController.task {
                tasks.append(task)

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tasks.count-1, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.task = task

        var rowChecked: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: tasks.count)

    if cell.accessoryView == nil {
                let cb = CheckButton()
                cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.accessoryView = cb
    }
            let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
            cb.check(self.rowChecked[indexPath.row])

            return cell
    }

func buttonTapped(_ target:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
            guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
            let point = touch.location(in: self.tableView)
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
        var tappedItem = tasks[indexPath!.row] as Task
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed
        tasks[indexPath!.row] = tappedItem
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `rowChecked` as a local variable and calling it with `self.rowChecked` as if it were a class property.

To solve this issue, remove the `self.` before `rowChecked`.

**Old:**

```
cb.check(self.rowChecked[indexPath.row])
```

**New:**

```
cb.check(rowChecked[indexPath.row])
```

There might be further issues, but that's the reason for the error as your code currently stands.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line: `var rowChecked: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: tasks.count)` inside the `tableView:cellForRowAt` method, so it's a local variable, it's not a property of the `LolFirstTableViewController` class.

That means you need to change this line: `cb.check(self.rowChecked[indexPath.row])` to `cb.check(rowChecked[indexPath.row])` (Removed `self.`).